# Grails global styling

Tags: grails

I was wondering how one would apply a global stylesheet to their entire site? I want to add twitter bootstrap, and a select number of other global styles, so that all the visuals are consistent.

Would I add a `<link>` to the layouts/main.gsp file?

**UPDATE**

Seems it's the css/main.css file that I'm interested in. Along with the layouts/main.gsp's reference to it. Could someone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default grails will use the "main" layout for scaffolding. So yes, those are the two files you are interested in.